# How to list processes detached in a script?

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, process, detach

I have:

```
$ cat ./test
#!/bin/bash

gulp dev &
```

Then run it:

```
$ ./test
...
```

(.. hit enter to get command prompt)
The command in the script starts `node` process. But I haven't it among background processes:

```
$ jobs -p
```

prints empty list. So the aim is to be able to list/kill (multiple) processes started and detached inside a single script. How to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interactive shell only manages the jobs that it started. When you run a script as a command, the background processes are started by the subshell, not the original shell.

You need to `source` the script, so that it will be run by your interactive shell:

```
source ./test
```

Comment: Great, it works! A little related question: alias seskill='kill $(jobs -p)' doesn't work (instead prints kill usage). How to cure?

Comment: `$(...)` runs in a subshell, so it can't list the jobs of the current shell.

Comment: so is it possible to create a shortcut to terminate all session's background processes?

Comment: This question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43527/bash-kill-background-jobs/43709#43709 says that your command should have worked.

Comment: Your alias works for me. I only get the usage message if I have no background jobs.